# When I try to blur the bg image, the entire body gets blurred :s

Tags: html, css, image, background, blur

Im trying to put a blurred background image as it follows in html

```
<body>        
<div class="fondoIndex"></div>
</body>
```

And then with css

```
.fondoIndex {
    background-image: url("images/bg3.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(5px);    
}
```

But it does not make any effect. No background is shown.
If I remove the close /div tag, the background image is shown and blurred, but so it is with the entire body. :S

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to specify the `height` and `width` of the element.

#### Explanation

As the `div` element is empty, by default its height value is `auto` so it'll take the height of the content. By adding the CSS rule forcing the element to have the required height and width it will show the background image as it have a height and width greater than 0.

```css
.fondoIndex {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Barbados_beach.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fondoIndex"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.fondoIndex {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/beautiful-artistic-image-of-environment-nature-in-spring-or-summer-picture-id1314315360?b=1&k=20&m=1314315360&s=170667a&w=0&h=vZ7ZKu_qL1b0MSNQyC7ru9u9jwY4JcMPvdZP1Imh3K8=");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fondoIndex"></div>
</body>

</html>
```